# Selecting the model attribute to display with a Wicket 7 DropDownChoice

Tags: java, wicket

Using Wicket 7, I've created a DropDownChoice component that uses a model derived from database entries.

Class Task contains two fields, the id and taskname. When queried, my database interface returns a List of Task objects. From this, I created a model class as follows:

```
public class TaskModel extends LoadableDetachableModel{
    @Override
    protected Object load() {
        try{
            TaskCriteria taskCriteria = new TaskCriteria();
            taskCriteria.listTask();
            return Arrays.asList(Task.listTaskByCriteria(taskCriteria));
        } catch (PersistentException pe){
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I then subclassed Panel to use in later pages, enclosing the DropDownChoice.

```
public class TaskDropDownPanel extends Panel{
    public TaskDropDownPanel(String id) {
        super(id);
        Form form = new Form("form");

        form.add(new DropDownChoice<Task>("tasks", new Model(null), new TaskModel()));
        add(form);
    }
}
```

Most everything seems to work, but the output I get from the DropDownChoice doesn't display the field I'd like. In this case, it just prints 1, 2, 3, 4 which I believe to be the ID of the Task in the database, though I'm not sure.

```
<select wicket:id="tasks" name="tasks">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Choose One</option>
    <option value="0">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
    <option value="3">4</option>
</select>
```

Is there a different derived model (e.g. PropertyModel) I should use with DropDownChoice? Ultimately, I want the taskname in the Task object to be the displayed text on the dropdown menu.

Comment: Note on the margin: I will use ALLWAYS type safe `public class TaskModel extends LoadableDetachableModel<List<Task>>`. I'm too old to guess "what type to return"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an `IChoiceRenderer`. Pass the renderer to your `DropDownChoice`. Check out the bottom of section 11.4 in the Wicket guide. https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/guide/modelsforms.html#modelsforms_4

Something like this:

```
ChoiceRenderer taskRenderer = new ChoiceRenderer("taskname", "id");
```

Comment: Cool, that's what I needed. Thx. For any future readers, my DropDownChoice became...         `form.add(new DropDownChoice<Task>("taskname", new Model(null), new TaskModel(), new ChoiceRenderer("taskname", "id")));`